# Declaration of variables in C

Tags: c, declaration

I have some problems because I need the `k` values varying through `nr`,  to apply in the `a` formulas. But inside the `if` the `k`values are not being declared to get into the `a` formulas. The error is in the row 63. Should I use vectors here?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void) {


    float Z = 0.2;
    float R = 0.03;


    int nr = 3; /* valores de nr apenas multiplos de 3*/
    int nz = 3;

    int i;
    int j;
    int a;

    float vetorq [nz];
    float h = 1;
    float b = 1;
    float c = nz/10;

    float K[nr] = {0};

    float T[nr][nz] = {0};


    for (i = 0; i< nz; i++){
       vetorq [i] = (h * exp(- (nz - b)*(nz - b)/ 2*c*c));
    }

    for (a = 0; a < (10*10*10*10); a++){


    for (i = 0; i < nz; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < nr; j++){



            if (0 <= j <= (nr/3)){
                 float ks = 1;
                 float ke = 1;
                 float kw = 1;
                 float kn = 1;
            }

            if ((nr/3) < j <= (2 * nr/3)){
                float ks = 2;
                float ke = 1;
                float kw = 1;
                float kn = 5;
            }

            if ((2 * nr/3) < j <= nr){
                float ks = 1;
                float ke = 7;
                float kw = 2;
                float kn = 1;
            }

error here
            float an = (i + (1.0 / 2.0)) * ((R * R)*nz*kn/ ((nr * nr))* Z);
            float ae = (i + 2.0) * Z * ke / nz;
            float aw = ((i+1.0) * kw * Z) / nz;
            float asul = (i + (1.0 / 2.0)) * (R * R)*nz*ks / (Z * (nr * nr));
            float ap = an + ae + aw + asul;
            float aef = 0;
```

Comment: declare "float ks;" with no assignment inside the first for loop before the first 'if' and then remove the 'float' before all the k variables.  Basically, declare them at the scope you need, initialize them in the if's

Comment: Which line is 63?  They're not numbered nor have you added a comment indicating the line with the error.

Comment: Defining a variable in a block limits its scope to that block.  The following (and other occurrences) are pointless and probably not as you intended:  `if (0 <= j <= (nr/3)){ float ks = 1; ...}`.

Comment: `if (0 <= j <= (nr/3))` doesn't do what you think. You have to write `if(0 <= j && j <= nr/3)`.

Comment: Declarations go out of scope when the nearest enclosing block is exited.  You need to decouple your declarations from your assignments.

Comment: Thanks guys, it works!

Comment: regarding statements like; `float Z = 0.2;
    float R = 0.03;` and similar, a `float` literal must have two things:  first. a decimal point `.`  second a trailing `f`.  Without the trailing `f` the literal is a `double`, not a `float`.  Without the decimal point, the literal is an`int`, not a `float`.